# I am able to successfully send from Firebase push notifications and receive them on mobile

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification

I am able to successfully send from Firebase push notifications and receive them on mobile. The payload which I receive has a lot of un-wanted information like time stamp and other things I don't want to display in the notification. Is there a Way to intercept the payload and modify it before the user receives the push notification [Here I want to filter the data before showing in the notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITaZd.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a simple way to handle and modify the title and the body of the notification before showing the notification to the user. But you can use the "data" section of the payload of your notification to send hidden values.

Comment: notification: {
        data:
        title: 
        body: 
        icon: 
        click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK'
      }   is this correct?